# How can I reach my JavaScript class from my html file?

Tags: javascript, html, function, class, dom

I'm having a shopping-page where everything works fine until I add a search function.

My JavaScript file is built with classes like:

- Products{getProducts}
- UI{displayProducts}
- Storage{saveProducts}
- DOMContentLoaded

which make things go in the correct order =>
get the products (from a JSON-file), store the products in `localStorage` and get them from the `localStorage` when they are needed.

In my HTML I have buttons where you can choose the category of the products. I have these set to `onclick => performTask`.

Since I haven't found out how to enter the `UI{displayProducts}` (*which is really what I want, since that's the only thing that should really happen when a button is pressed - show the correct products*) - I have made a new function in my js-file. This function works very much as the `DOMContentLoaded` and at first, it seems it's working really well, until you restart the app a couple of times and try to change a number of products in the cart or remove all items in the cart.

If I for example want to add an extra copy of an item already in the cart, the value will not be added by one, but with one plus all the items in the cart. If I try to remove all the items in the cart, I will have to do it as many times as I have restarted and added things to the app.

Therefore I wonder if I somehow can reach the class `UI{displayProducts}` directly from my HTML-file and in the UI-class add the filter for displaying the correct products? And how? Is there a better solution?

Of course, I can add some code if you like, just let me know which part since the code is quite lengthy.

```
class Products {
    async getProducts(){
        try{
            const res = await fetch('/data/products.json');
            const data = await res.json();
            let products = data.items;
            products = products.map(item => {
                const {id,category,title,color,price} = item;
                const image = item.image.url;
                return {id,category,title,color,price,image}
            })
            return products;
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class UI {
    displayProducts(products){
        // This is where the products get displayed
    }
}
```

```
class Storage {
  static saveProducts(products) {
    localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
  }
  static getProduct(id) {
    let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
    return products.find((product) => product.id === id);
  }
  static saveCart(cart) {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
  }
  static getCart() {
    return localStorage.getItem("cart")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
      : [];
  }
}
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  const ui = new UI();
  const products = new Products();
  ui.setupAPP();
  products
    .getProducts()
    .then((products) => {
      ui.displayProducts(products);
      Storage.saveProducts(products);
    })
})
```

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="category-button" onclick="displaySearch(new UI, new Products, 'beds')"><a href="#hidden">beds</a></li>
    <li class="category-button" onclick="displaySearch(new UI, new Products, 'sofas')"><a href="#hidden">sofas</a></li>
    <li class="category-button" onclick="displaySearch(new UI, new Products, 'dressers')"><a href="#hidden">dressers</a></li>
    <li class="category-button" onclick="displaySearch(new UI, new Products, 'news')"><a href="#hidden">news</a></li>
</ul>
```

goes to the "new" function `displaySearch` (which I'd rather not use).

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking... You need to show code

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript HTML importing**

If i've understood what you're asking, you will first need to import your JS file into your html file with:

`<script src='path_to_js.js' type='text/javascript'>`

This esentially adds the contents of that file between two `<script>` tags

**Accessing class functions**

Because your function is wrapped within a class, you will have to create an instance of this class within your HTML file. This can be done within some `<script>` tags like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

      myClassInstance = new UI();

</script>
```

Then, you can use this instance to access the functions offered by the class:

```
<button onClick='myClassInstance.my_function_name();'> Click Me! </button>
```

**Declaration of classes in Javascript**

Classes in JS follow a rigid structure and may not work if this structure is not followed. I am yet to understand the need to wrap your functions within classes but below is an example of how your class should look. Bare in mind that it is a REQUIREMENT to include a constructor in your class which must be named `constructor()` and that none of the classes methods need the `function` keyword before them.

```
class UI {

      constructor(class_args_here){ // MUST be named 'constructor'

            // anything that needs to run when the class is instantiated with "new MyClassName();"

      }

      my_first_method(){ // this is where your function should be (note no 'function' keyword before)

            // method contents

      }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but that is no problem. The issue occurs when I, from my HTML, try to reach a function within a class in my javascript-file. In this case I want to reach my displayProducts function, which lies in the UI class. The class is what causes the problem.

Comment: @Battleaxe I understand now what you mean and have changed my post to reflect what I believe your solution is

Comment: Thank you, but that won't work :( I've tried it, and I just tried again. As you can see in my DOMContentLoaded I have const UI = new UI(); And in my HTML I have <button>onclick='UI.displayProducts'  ==> UI.displayProducts is not a function

Comment: @Battleaxe could you provide me with a link/pastebin with your code so that I can see. A few possible issues that spring to mind involve syntax. Remember in a class, methods do not need the 'function' keyword before them. Also you should avoid using the same variable name as the class name like you have in the above message as this could confuse some browsers and makes it more difficult to read

Comment: @Battleaxe no worries, go to https://pastebin.com and paste your code into the box. Tweak the settings below to make sure that it is publicly available for me to see and hit 'create new paste'. It should give you a link you can send to me here. Check back on my post, i've added some more info about classes. You may want to check that your class follows the structure I have detailed or that could be the issue :)

Comment: :) I believe this was the last ok code, haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226319/discussion-between-battleaxe-and-matthew-swallow).

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code**

There are two main things from your code that have jumped out at me straight away. A couple of quite simple fixes so you dont need to be re-writing anything.

*Constructors (I don't think you will need any)*

As detailed in my above post, you will need to add constructors to your classes IF anything needs instantiating when an instance of the class is created.
If your constructor as you plan it will look like this: `constructor() {}` or `constructor(val1, val2) {}` then you don't need one as the interpreter will add this by default, but if you plan to have anything execute the moment the `new UI();` line is ran then you MUST have one.

*Parsing Classes Through Functions*

In your html, you have: `onclick="displaySearch(new UI, new Products, 'beds')"`.
Because each instance of the `Product()` and `UI()` classes never changes, it is messy to create another every time this function is run and I don't believe you can pass an instance around functions like this. You should instead create these instances just above your `displaySearch()` function, making them globally available for that function.

Below is an example of what I mean:

```
uiClass = new UI(); // these variables can be used anywhere in the code now
productsClass = new Products(); // ^^^^^^^

/** TO ENABLE SEARCH-FUNCTION **/
function displaySearch(search) {

    var products = productsClass.getProducts() // make a local variable products equal to the result of the getProducts() method. Then continue as was.
       
    .....
   
}
```